# translateX in ngStyle has no effect when updating dynamically. Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have this property which updates dynamically:

```
 <h5 class="s{{i + 1}}" [style.transform]="'translateX(' + venuescroll + ')'">{{locations.name}}</h5>
```

Is this wrong? I update this value when scrolling. 
The value of `venuescroll` is 32px and is increasing.

Comment: may you post venuescroll value and how it is increasing?

Comment: @fatemefazli when i scroll left for every pixel i move the `venuescroll` value increases from 20px to 21px and so on. I've set a default value of 20px in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if venuescroll is number it should be:

```
<h5 class="s{{i + 1}}" [style.transform]="'translateX(' + venuescroll + 'px)'">{{locations.name}}</h5>
```

ts code:

```
 location = {name:'test'}
  venuescroll = 32

  ngOnInit(){
    setInterval(()=>{
        this.venuescroll = this.venuescroll + 1;
    },2000)
  }
```

working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6xatv).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this
 [ngStyle]="{'transform': 'translateX(' + venuescroll + ')'}"

Thank You and Best Regards

Abhay Patidar